# Can I implement Stripe Connect in IOS App?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have read all detail about stripe payment section here. https://stripe.com/docs/connect

But unable to understand  subscriptions section of this page. Please tell me how to implement stripe connect in ios app using objective-C.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Read this Article :- http://www.raywenderlich.com/30092/how-to-accept-credit-cards-in-your-ios-apps-using-stripe

Comment: Thanks for this link. Can you tell me also about coupons implementation in stripe on client side.how to verify coupons in stripe on ios app.

Answer (score 5):

The difference between Stripe and Stripe Connect is who plays the "merchant" role.

With regular stripe the merchant is the app provider.  For example an app created by "Barney's Pizza" - The app can collect payment using Stripe for pizzas.  In this case Barney's merchant details are built in to the app.

With Stripe connect the app user can register as the "merchant".  For example, you create an app that allows small businesses to invoice clients.  After they install the app, the user would configure *their* Stripe account into the app so that they received the payments.  Stripe Connect also allows the app developer to charge a fee that is a percentage of the amount - so your app could be free to download but users would pay you a percentage for every charge they made.

Stripe Connect allows users to create an account with Stripe if they don't already have one, which makes the program flow a bit more complex in an app (On the web, the Stripe web site takes care of it for you, redirecting back to your page once it is done).

This answer suggests one approach to using Stripe Connect in iOS - [How to use Stripe Connect in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865625/how-to-use-stripe-connect-in-an-ios-app)

Comment: According to the Stripe Connect documentation you can charge a fee (in cents), so for $100 you would need to specify a fee of 9000 when you send the transaction (Stripe also takes a fee, so you would need to factor that in to your calculations)

Comment: I think it would be very complex to do purely on the client side due to the need to support account creation.  You could perhaps use a UIWebView

Comment: Sorry. StackOverflow is about getting help with specific problems.  I can't write your code for you.  Perhaps you could try http://careers.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Can we do it using stripe SDK ?