# Implementing stripe connect directly from within an iOS app

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

There is a post re: implementing stripe connect from a couple of years ago.

[How to use Stripe Connect in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865625/how-to-use-stripe-connect-in-an-ios-app)

I have built an app where only User A needs to register and login while User B can choose from a list of User As and i am trying to set up the app so User B can pay directly to a User A.

While the basic version of stripe is relatively easy to implement Stripe connect is giving me a bit of grief.

Specifically there is an example called Rocket Rider on github (which is meant to.mimic uber, etc.) made by stripe but in this example the "Pilot" had to register via a website.

I'd like it all to happen from within my app. I've read the docs a few.times now and still a touch uncertain.

Is the post from a few years ago still relevant? Is the only way to have the registration done via the app to use a webview?

In the stripe docs there is a section https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/standard

Which essentially goes through the implementation for iOS. But I wasn't sure if these docs only refer to payment that as the developer I would receive if say I was selling a product to users.

Again, in my app there is a list of User As and each User A would register ideally within the app and then User B can choose who to pay. I wasn't sure if the "Standard" doc above also refers to this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: @Mike This isn't really a programming question. I'd recommend that you write to Stripe support at https://support.stripe.com/email and include as much details as you can about your business model and desired flow of funds.

Answer (score 1):

Been looking into the same thing today (March 2019) and have a few answers for you

The current state of the Stripe Cocoa Pod does not have anything that has to do with connect accounts. That will not help you in any way with creating connect accounts.

All is not lost. If you must stay in-app, you may create what is called a [Custom Account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts)--This means that you are responsible for the UI, User Validation, and Communication. Your users will not be able to use the Lovely Express Dashboard either....but you can stay in app.

As you alluded to, you are still able to use Safari to open Stripe Express and have your app handle the deep linking once the experience is complete. While this is an annoyance, there are some serious perks to having the Express experience. You don't have to deal anything bank account related because the Express Dashboard will handle it for you and Stripe will handle all verification communication. (Outside app).

TLDR: You can do it completely in app using Custom Accounts......but you'll be on your own!